# ObjectParameterError: Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got search

Tags: node.js, reactjs, regex, mongodb, mongoose

this get route is giving no error in post-man but doing the same with frontend giving error in node console:

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got search
```

**although response are fetched**.

get controller

```
const Recent = require("../models/recent");
const getRecentByName = async (req, res, next) => {
  const name = req.params.name;
  let regex = new RegExp(name, "i");
  let players;
  try {
    players = await Recent.find({ name: { $regex: regex } });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  if (!players) {
    return next("no player found");
  }
  // console.log(players);
  res.json({ players });
};  

exports.getRecentByName = getRecentByName;
```

fetching from frontend:

```
const searchRecords = async () => {
    const data = await sendRequest(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/player/recent/search/" + search,
      "GET"
    );

    setRecord(data.players);
  };
```

Recent:(mongoose Schema):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const recentSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  recent: [
    {
      team1: { type: String },
      team2: { type: String },
      points: { type: Number, required: true },
      date: { type: Date },
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Recent", recentSchema);
```

Comment: What is Recent?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from the front and in the URL
you should use
`http://localhost:5000/api/player/recent/search/${search}`